# Update 3 column in same time 2nd table all field varchar update help of phone number

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, inner-join

```
UPDATE db2.customer e1 
SET
( 
 e1.userId,            
 e1.Email Id,        
 e1.Date of birth
 )=
 (SELECT  ur.userId,ur.emailId,ur.dob FROM db1.user ur WHERE db1.user.mobileNo=db2.customer.mobile NO )
```

Database 1st and user table

```
mobileNo      | userId  |emailId              | dob 
---------------------------------------------------------    
1111111111    |   1     |  cve@gmail.com      |30-12-2013
2222222222    |   2     |  ehs@gmail.com      |20-12-2012
5555555555    |   3     | hsdj@gmail.com      |01-12-2013
6666666666    |   4     |  tr@gmail.com       |02-12-2010
```

database 2nd table customer

```
mobile No    | userId         |    Email Id          | Date of birth 
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
1111111111   |  null          |   null               |null
2222222222   |   null         |   null               |null
3333333333   |   null         |   null               |null
7777777777   |   null         |   null               |null
```

I want update my `db2.customer` where phone number matches all update userId, Email Id, Date of birth

My query does not work---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE db2.customer e1 
INNER JOIN db1.user ur ON e1.mobileNo = ur.`mobile NO`
SET e1.userId = ur.userId, 
    e1.`Email Id` = ur.EmailId, 
    e1.`Date of birth` = ur.dob;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE db2.customer e1
   SET e1.userId = e2.userId, 
   e1.Email Id=e2.Email Id,
   e1.Date of birth=e2.Date of birth
   FROM db1.user as 'e2'
    WHERE
    db1.user.mobileNo=db2.customer.mobileNO;
```